# Reshape a Tensorflow dataset preprocessed with timeseries_dataset_from_array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, sliding-window

*Note: I have already read [How to reshape BatchDataset class tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234067/how-to-reshape-batchdataset-class-tensor) but the solution doesn't apply here.*

As mentioned in [Train a neural network with input as sliding windows of a matrix with Tensorflow / Keras, and memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088246/train-a-neural-network-with-input-as-sliding-windows-of-a-matrix-with-tensorflow), I need to train a neural network with all sliding windows of shape (16, 2000) from a matrix of shape (10000, 2000). (In my other post it's 100k, but here 10k is ok).

```
import tensorflow
import numpy as np
X = np.array(range(20000000)).reshape(10000, 2000)  
X = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, None, 16, sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=32)
for b in X:
    print(b)  # Tensor of shape (32, 16, 2000)
    break
```

The problem is that I need to feed it into a model which **requires a (..., 16, 2000, 1) shape**.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(9, 9), activation='relu', input_shape=(16, 2000, 1), padding='same'))
...
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=8)
```

I tried

```
X = tensorflow.reshape(X, (-1, 16, 2000, 1))
```

without success.

How to do this, i.e. have the output of `timeseries_dataset_from_array` of shape `(..., 16, 2000, 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a transformation to each element of a `tf.data.Dataset` you should use the [`tf.data.Dataset.map` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map). In your case, you could define the function with a `lambda`, using [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims?hl=en):

```
ds = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, None, 16, sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=32)
ds_correct_shape = ds.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x,axis=-1))
```

If we check the shape of the first element:

```
>>> for elem in ds_correct_shape.take(1):
        print(f"{elem.shape=}")
elem.shape=TensorShape([32, 16, 2000, 1])
```

Comment: It should work out of the box. Without the Traceback, it's hard to debug though.

Comment: More precisely @Lescurel, I have `X = timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, None, 16, ...)` and `Y = timeseries_dataset_from_array(Y, None, 16, ...)`. Then `model.fit(X, Y)` does not work, one has to group X, Y inside a *single* dataset `ds` and then `model.fit(ds)`, how would you do that? (create `ds` from `X` and `Y`)

Comment: Ah, then, you can use `tf.data.Dataset.zip(X,Y)` to create a single dataset.